# Cannot access local method variable in pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I have the following method:

```
  def update
    loan = Loan.find(params[:id])
    pry
    respond_with loan.update(loan_params) 
  end
```

So I would expect that when I get to pry in the console I should be able to type loan and get the object but instead I get "undefined local variable or method 'loan'", am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. I am using Pry also but to get a breakpoint I usually use `binding.pry`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use `binding.pry` which will load pry in the scope of your current object (I think `pry` just loads a pry session without the scope.)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Comment: `pry` loads a Pry session in the context of `self`. If you are curious in more details, please read this: http://kyrylo.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/05/29/so-what-is-binding-pry-exactly